# Capture Execution time of PIG queries during sentiment analysis

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

So I'am learning how to do sentiment analysis of twitter data using PIG, I am currently referring to [this](https://acadgild.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-tweets-afinn-dictionary/) blog for sentiment analysis and I am successful in doing so. Now I need to capture the time taken for the each line of query and display it on the GRUNT shell.

**For Example**
  I should display the time taken for the following command to execute

```
dictionary = LOAD '/AFINN.txt' using PigStorage('\t') AS(word:chararray,rating:int);  
dump dictionary;
```

After executing the `dump dictionary` command the whole file is shown on the `GRUNT` shell but I am not able to see the time taken by the MapReduce program to execute.

Comment: Does saving your script and running it through CLI and not from inside grunt show any different/extra stats. A Pig job generally has a map-reduce summary at the end which has information about no. of mappers/reducers, alias' computed and time taken from each MR stage. Also check whether your are indeed running in map-reduce mode and not local model.